# Find matrix-valued function with a given derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Given $t$ and matrix-valued function $\mathbf{X}_t$, is it possible to find (analytically or computationally) matrix-valued function $\mathbf{C}_t$ such that the following holds?

$$\mathbf{X}_{t} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} t} \exp{\mathbf{C}_t}$$

$\mathbf{X}_t$ is a $m \times m$ block triangular matrix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we consider the 1*1 case, the problem becomes very easy.

Comment: Then solve it and post it in your question. Then list what goes wrong when you're no longer dealing with $1 \times 1$ matrices. Salami tactics — one thin slice at a time.

Comment: Take the time-integral of both sides, then isolate $C(t)$ on the LHS 
$$C(t) = \log\left(e^{C(0)} + \int_0^t X(s)\,ds\right)$$ or do you require some specific form for a solution?